# Cargar un valor aleatorio entre 2 parametros en c++

Tags: c++, c

Estoy intentando hacer una funcion en la que se guarde en una variable un numero aleatorio entre dos numeros (en este caso, entre 3 y 6) y no se como hacer. Se que existe la funcion srand, pero me carga solo basura y   no se que está mal.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

void cargarnAleatorio(int v){

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        v=(rand()%6)+3;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Como he dicho otras tantas veces, C no es C++. Son lenguajes independientes y las respuestas orientadas a uno de los dos lenguajes no tienen por qué ser portables al otro lenguaje:

**Solución C**

Lo primero que debes tener en cuenta es que la generación de números aleatorios solo debe generarse **una sola vez**. La función `time()` devuelve una marca de tiempo **en segundos**, luego si invocas esta función varias veces en el mismo segundo **obtendrás el mismo resultado** varias veces.

Por otro lado, para que la asignación que haces dentro de la función sea visible fuera de la misma es necesario recurrir al uso de punteros. El parámetro `v` debe ser, por tanto, un puntero.

Así pues sería recomendable que el código luciese así:

```
srand(time(NULL)); // <<--- Solo se inicializa el generador una vez
int numeros[6];
for( int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    cargarAleatorio(&numeros[i]);
}

void cargarnAleatorio(int *v)
{
    *v=(rand()%4)+3;
}
```

Nota que hay otra corrección. Entre el número máximo (6) y el mínimo (3), ambos incluídos, hay exactamente 4 números (3, 4, 5, 6), luego el valor del módulo debe ser 4, no 6.

**Solución C++ (pre C++11)**

Lo ideal en este caso es usar referencias en vez de punteros. Las referencias tienen en este caso dos ventajas frente a los punteros:

- No se puede asignar `NULL` a una referencia, lo cual ya nos previene de ciertos errores
- Las referencias permiten escribir código más legible.

La solución podría quedar así:

```
srand(time(NULL)); // <<--- Solo se inicializa el generador una vez
int numeros[6];
for( int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    cargarAleatorio(numeros[i]);
}

void cargarnAleatorio(int & v)
{
    v=(rand()%4)+3;
}
```

**C++ (C++11 en adelante)**

Desde el año 2011 existe en C++ una librería específica para trabajar con números aleatorios. Es más potente y segura que `rand()`, por lo que se recomienda su uso:

```
void CargarAleatorio(int &v)
{
    // Un generador basado aleatorio muy bueno pero muy lento.
    // Se usa para inicializar un generador más rápido
    static std::random_device rd;
   
    // Un generador mucho más rápido. Utilizaremos este para generar los números
    // aleatorios  
    static std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 

    // Esta clase nos permite elegir cómo será la distribución de los resultados.
    // En este caso queremos una distribución uniforme (todos los números serán equiprobables)
    // en el rango 3-6 
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(3, 6);
 
    // Se genera el número aleatorio
    v = distrib(gen);
}
```

**Notas finales**: En cualquier caso, estas funciones estarían mejor escritas si devolviesen el valor vía `return`. Hay que intentar que los parámetros de la función sean valores de entrada, dejando el `return` para los valores de salida

Answer (score 1):

La funion rand la has usado bien pero tu funcion no debuelve el resultado.Para que lo debuelva tienes que pasarle a la funcion una direcion de memoria (que seria la de tu variable) en vez de un int y almacenarla en un puntero. Esto seria algo asi:

funcion:

```
void cargarnAleatorio(int *v){

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        *v=(rand()%6)+3;
  }
```

llamada:

```
int aleatorio;
cargarnAleatorio(&aleatorio);
```

&-->direccion de memoria

*-->puntero

(Perdon si no he puesto ni una tilde pero esque estoy usando un teclado ingles)

Answer (score 1):

En C y C++ por default a las funciones los parametros se les pasan por copia.
Eso significa que `cargarnAleatorio` no recibe el `int` que le pasaste
originalmente, sino que recibe una copia de el.

Puedes pasarle un puntero a tu variable como menciona @julianix, o como veo que
tu codigo en especifico es de C++, puedes indicar que lo pasas por referencia y
podras usar la variable normalmente.

Para indicar que es una referencia colocas un `&` al lado del tipo de la
variable. En tu caso quedaria asi:

```cpp
void cargarnAleatorio(int &v) {
  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
  v = (rand() % 6) + 3;
}
```